# How to create text with a size proportional to a rectangle

Tags: java, android

[Screenshot for context](http://www.neato3000.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screenshot_2016-11-01-17-29-22.png)

So I have created a little menu system that uses RectF for each button. This is mainly for persistant options, like inverting the accelerometer's X orY axis, or setting the number of dots displayed. The dimensions for the buttons are calculated using the screen size and orientation so that they look the same size on every device, and whichever orientation.

So since I have these rectangles defined, I would like to put text in them that is scaled to those rectangles. One way I thought of was to draw large text to a bitmap that is the hieght of the text bounds height of "Aq" and just wide enough for the text. With that, I could just scale the bitmap down to the size proportional to the recatngles. But I'm not sure it is the most efficient way of doing this. Is there some math for calculating the text size property (in the Paint object?) based on the dimensions of these rectangles so that I can just use DrawText to place the text over these rectangles? Or should I just use the bitmap idea?

Comment: Look at [this library](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView) or [this library](https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView). They are auto-sizing `TextViews`, designed to scale their font to fit the available space. They may give you some ideas. I would not go with the draw-to-a-bitmap option, as I am sure that there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: Well, it sounds good. However, I do not understand these view things, ha ha. I'm a bit new to some of the way things are structured in Android. I probably should have mentioned that this app is (from what I understand) one view, that a canvas draws to (I may be wrong on the phtrasing, ha ha) so I am using things like drawCircle, and drawRect on the canvas to get items on the screen. Thanks for confirming the bitmap idea was bogus!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the text size is actually the height of the text, so I just gave it a size that is half the value of the height of the rectangle it was to be drawn in. Poof it's a perfect size every time. From there, I set the alignment on the text to centered, and placed drew the text at the center coordinates of the rectangle. I also had to add half of the size from the text to the texts y coordinate so the text would center.

```
 canvas.drawText("Flip X Axis",myRect.centerX(),myRect.centerY()+ (textSize/2), myPaint);
```

[Result](http://www.neato3000.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screenshot_2016-11-08-14-27-12.png)